# Set tags for imported struct in Go

Tags: json, encoding, struct, go, go-gorm

I'm using [gorm](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm) (**g**o **orm**) to retrieve data from my database that will be encoded in JSON. Gorm provides a default struct for primary keys and time tracking, whose DeletedAt attribute should not be encoded in JSON.

I've written a small example, that **doesn't** output the password but the DeletedAt attribute is still visible.

```go
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

// Struct from the gorm package:
//
// type Model struct {
//     ID        uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
//     CreatedAt time.Time
//     UpdatedAt time.Time
//     DeletedAt *time.Time
// }

// Defines the database model for gorn
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username string `json:"username" sql:"size:32; not null; unique"`
    Password string `json:"password" sql:"not null"`
    Locale   string `json:"locale"   sql:"not null"`
}

// Public JSON version of database model
type PublicUser struct {
    *User
    DeletedAt bool `json:"deletedAt,omitempty"`
    Password  bool `json:"password,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("sqlite3", "storage.db")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    u := &User{}
    db.Where("id = ?", 3).Find(&u)

    json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(PublicUser{
        User: u,
    })
}
```

This is the ourput I get if I run my script:

```
{
    "ID":3,
    "CreatedAt":"2015-05-13T14:54:23.5577227Z",
    "UpdatedAt":"2015-05-13T14:54:23.5577227Z",
    "DeletedAt":null,
    "username":"dan",
    "locale":"en_US"
}
```

I modified the [example](https://play.golang.org/p/WQxbLSUX4R) of Alfred Rossi to imitate the behavior and I got the same result.

Comment: Case matters. You need to set the DeletedAt bool to serialize as `json:"DeletedAt,omitempty". Captial D to clobber "DeletedAt" in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just shadow the field with a bool set to false and tag it with `omitempty`

For example

```
type User struct {
    Username  string `json:"username"`
    DeletedAt int    `json:"deleted_at"`
}

type PublicUser struct {
    *User
    DeletedAt bool `json:"deleted_at,omitempty"`
}
```

Feel free to play with it [here](http://play.golang.org/p/vJoCAoMm4v). Also see [this blog post](http://attilaolah.eu/2014/09/10/json-and-struct-composition-in-go/) of Attila Oláh.

Comment: Using the shadowing approach worked great if you have just one parent struct but in my case I have a grandparent-struct (gorm.Model) which can't be shadowed. [Look here](https://play.golang.org/p/WQxbLSUX4R).

Comment: Shadowing works fine, the problem is that the Json key is set to deletedAt and you are shadowing deleted_at

Comment: My fault. Thanks again Mr. Rossi.